# Best way to create a dropdown filter?

Tags: php, sorting, filter, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to filter information to make it easy for a visitor to find.  Ideally I would have a few dropdown filters to sort the data and only the posts matching the options selected would be shown.  I have hardly a clue as to how this is done, except through php.  I found a nice example of what I'm trying to do right here:

http://www.darienps.org/dhs/courses.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into AJAX? Using some JavaScript (perhaps a library of your choosing), you would make what are called AJAX calls to some server-side logic (probably to query the database) to return the desired data. If you're not familiar with this, I can tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is really what you want to know, but assuming you'd construct a database query to do the search, you'd have to test in your PHP each parameter of the form (each dropdown), if it is set or not.
If it is set, you'd just add a restriction in your database query (in the `WHERE` clause).
This would return the results matching the parameters selected by the user.